# Bigger than any other city in/of the world

Tags: word-choice

> Shangai is bigger than any other city 'in' the world

. Can we also say it like

> bigger than any other city of the world?

Are they both correct?

Comment: Prefer superlative and not comparative when you are talking about the city that is the most populated (biggest in your language here!) as compared to any other city in the world. In case of stating the population, it's always superlative. The most populated country, state or city etc. *Shanghai is the most populated (biggest?) city in the world.*

Comment: Maulik, If we say it in comparative, 'in' or 'of' should we use?

Comment: If you compare, it'll take the other city and not the world! Shanghai is bigger than Tokyo! Anyway, both are correct. I checked many references. Nevertheless, I'd prefer *in the world* for stating the population and *of* the world if I'm talking about some possession or connection. *Shanghai is the commercial city of China.* See the possession there.

Comment: Check my edited answer. I found the exact thing in Swan's.

Answer (score 3):

In this context, I would only say **in the world**.  Maybe that's because I'm an American.  But **of the world** doesn't sound right to my ears.  In fact, if you google anything with a superlative + on, for example, **the biggest building of the world** it gives you only answers with **in the world**.

Comment: I'm British and I too would only say *in the world*.

Comment: Thank you pal. What does it mean to say: creativity is being "demanded of executives"?

Comment: @ Vijay.  We usually address men with "pal". So, be careful if you don't know whether the person you're talking to is male or female. :-)

Comment: Ya thank you. How to call you then? Also i remind you of answering the question in previous comment pls.

Comment: You just say:  **Thanks.** You can't make any mistakes with that.  Regarding your other question, I recommend you post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

> Biggest city *in* AND biggest city *of* -both seem okay to me. Also, I searched on COCAE and some other resources and could find examples of both.

Nevertheless, if you still want to be specific, I may see a subtle difference there. I'd use *of* when talking about possession or connection in this case.

> Shanghai is the biggest city (most populated) in the world. But...
>  
>   Shanghai is the commercial city *of* China - See the possession there.

**This is the exact thing I found in Swan's 3rd Edition, Section 139**

> With superlative degree, we don't use *of* with a singular word referring to a place or group.

In fact, this was mentioned under the title of **35 mistakes that intermediate students often make.**
Which is the biggest city *of* the world - Incorrect.
Which is the biggest city *in* the world - Correct.

The superlative degree takes *of* before plurals and before *lot* -

> She's the fastest player of them all. 
>   He's the best of the lot.

Answer (score 1):

As others note, the conventional English phrasing is "in the world".

Note that this has nothing to do with the fact that you are saying it is "biggest", or using a superlative in general. In general we refer to places being "in", "on", or "at" other places, not "of" other places. For example, we would say, "Shanghai is a big city in China", not "of China". Or, "I visited a fascinating city in China named Shanghai." Likewise "Devon is a county in Britain", not "of Britain". "Elm Street is in the north section of town." "My apartment is in the basement." Etc.

We sometimes use "of" for a place-in-a-place if we are trying to express the idea of belonging rather than location. Like, "The cities of China are crowded." "Wall Street is the heart of New York."

There are cases where either "in" or "of" would work, when either the meaning of location or belonging could be appropriate.